# End a while loop in the event a condition is met

Tags: vba, loops, while-loop

I am in the process of converting Mathcad code into VBA and am trying to figure out how to replicate the While loop, which asks the program to run the loop while TGuess < 0. At the end of the loop is an if statement to break the loop if sGuess>1/1.4 (I would attach a picture, but my reputation does not allow me to).

I have written this code in VBA, but am wondering if including the sGuess variable in the original While statement is correct, or if it could influence the output of the loop:

```
    While TGuess < 0 And sGuess <= 1 / 1.4

        kterm = (kj ^ (1 / 6)) / 26 'k term in the numerator of depth equation
                    epw = 3 / 5
        FDepth = ((kterm * RainInt * L * CF) / sGuess ^ 0.5) ^ epw

        tflow = UW_Wat * g * sGuess * FDepth    'Calc Flow Shear Stress

        pflow = 7.853 * UW_Wat * (tflow / UW_Wat) ^ (3 / 2)

        TGuess = pflow - pcrit   'Recalc TGuess as E-P
        sGuess = sGuess + SlopeInc  'Calc new stable slope
    Wend
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the initial value of sGuess?

Comment: short answer is it is ok to have multiple conditions in the `While ___` bit. And yes it will influence the output of the loop if sGuess exceeds 1/1.4 but that is what you want isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To mitigate your concern, it might be better to replace the while...wend loop with a Do While ... Loop block.  You can then put your break condition where you'd have it in the corresponding Mathcad code by using something along the lines of

```
If sGuess > 1/1.4 Then
    Exit Do
End If
```